# Can you help me understand the masked man paradox?

Tags: epistemology, fallacies, modal-logic, paradox, masked-man

The masked man fallacy (or paradox) is roughly:

> Premise 1: I don't know who the man wearing the mask is.
> Premise 2: The man wearing the mask is my father.
> Premise 3: I know who my father is.
> Conclusion: Absurdity (How can I know my father but not know the masked man if they are the same person?)

The hidden assumption is Liebniz's Law: that two things that are identical (namely, the masked man and my father) must have the same properties (namely, being known to me). But to me this premise is incontestable.

To me, the paradox evokes a kind of "quantum weirdness". If you allow intensional properties such as "known-ness" to be a part of your ontology, then weird stuff happens. In such a universe, it seems that things don't really exist, only aspects. i.e. my father is an aspect, the masked man is an aspect. It seems to fundamentally bring into question the notions of being and identity.

As you can see, I'm thoroughly confused. The explanations I've seen in terms of intensional contexts (basically, you just can't substitute like for like in the scope of certain verbs) have been unenlightening. How would you formalize the argument in logic?

--
PS
I want to mention another interesting aspect of this issue. Whenever I've tried to explain or write the paradox to someone, it is kind of impossible! If you tell someone: "You don't know who the masked man is. But he is your father." Well now they know who he is! If you rephrase in the 3rd person it's no longer an issue ("John doesn't know who the masked man is, but *you know* it's John's father"), but still, I wonder if that could be a useful observation...

Comment: There's no intensional confusion but veils. Suppose the number of planets in our solar system equals 8 and everyone knows 8 is necessarily greater than 7 after learning arithmetic. But obviously the number of planets in our solar system is *not* necessarily greater than 7 due to some other easily conceivable possible world(s)...

Comment: duplicate: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/111080/73257

[but I do prefer this one]

Comment: Things like "known-ness" are called propositional attitudes and the "weirdness" of not being able to substitute co-referring terms in their context is called Frege's puzzle. There is a long discussion of it and proposed solutions in [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/prop-attitude-reports/index.html#FrePuz).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the failure of substitutivity in an intensional context simply due to a lack of clarity in terms of the identity operator?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/111080/is-the-failure-of-substitutivity-in-an-intensional-context-simply-due-to-a-lack)

Answer (score 1):

**This is very much just a question of [sense and reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense_and_reference)**. The classic example of this is [Hesperus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesperus) and [Phosphorus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus_(morning_star)), the morning star and evening stars, which Frege discussed in the context of [puzzles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frege%27s_puzzles) meant to highlight these issues.

**In the philosophy of language, there has always been some question about how we can determine or not if two things are identical.** One solution to your quantum weirdness is to accept there are limits to your knowledge and judgments of truth. Thus, if you see a masked man and do not know it is your father before you then at that time, then for practical purposes, you [reality is constructed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(philosophy_of_science)) from observations and corresponding propositions as to entertain two distinct people until you are corrected.

**This is follows from the [defeasibility of practical reasoning (SEP)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reasoning-defeasible/).** 'Unknown person A is masked', and 'Person B is your father and not present' are two propositions that arise from your initial observations. These propositions do not in anyway contradict each other. We may consider a change in the system, later, you witness the police unmask the unknown person who known to you. **Knowing your father is not the same as knowing someone is your father at a particular place and time.** You aren't omniscient. In this way, the psychological weirdness you experience is just what [Dennett calls a deepity (YT)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EuhcxZs1qg). Let's adapt his schema:

> - It's true you don't know that the masked person is your father. (trivial truth)
> - It's false that you don't know that 'the masked person is your father' after you find out. (trivial falsity)
> - So on reflection you note 'I didn't know the masked person is my father' AND 'I did know the masked person, my father'! (the deepity).

In the spirit of Dennett: WHOA!!!! You knew contradictory facts to be true simultaneously, which suggests the person was and wasn't my father (in the same spirit as Schrödinger's Cat) except, a glance at the fine print shows that's not actually the case. It's an illusion that stems from the same violation of the [use-mention distinction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) (and perhaps importantly an equivocation on 'knowing' and 'knowing that') that Dennett underscores in his clip. :D

**Interestingly, we don't seem to be as susceptible to the experience when talking about abstractions.** Let's say you have a variable x, and you know that y=7, and then you come to find out that x=y=7. Does that seem to be a great mystery? Do we experience the deepity? Does it trigger some sense of [cognitive dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance)? Not in this example. There's something about believing you know and didn't know it was your father at the same time that seems surreal when applied to physical reality!

EDIT

Okay, I couldn't wait. I'll take a shot at formalization, but I don't think epistemic modal logic is necessary.

#### Formalization of Paradox

When one is told the paradox, one formulates three propositions using K<sub>I</sub> as know(I,p) where p is a proposition from set P:

> **P<sub>1</sub>**: K<sub>I</sub> "father = man"
> **P<sub>2</sub>**: K<sub>I</sub> "masked(man)"
> **P<sub>3</sub>**: K<sub>I</sub> "masked(father)"

But if one thinks about it again, one might also arrive at:

> **P'<sub>1</sub>**: K<sub>I</sub> "father = man"
> **P'<sub>2</sub>**: K<sub>I</sub> "masked(man)"
> **P'<sub>3</sub>**: ¬K<sub>I</sub> "masked(father)"

The paradox is created by the cognitive dissonance that results from the contradiction of  **P<sub>3</sub>** and  **P'<sub>3</sub>**. On one level, you know the father is masked, but on another level you know that you don't KNOW that the father is masked. This is the paradox.

#### Dissolution of Paradox

The difference comes in HOW one arrives at each  **P<sub>3</sub>** and  **P'<sub>3</sub>**. In the case of the first  **P<sub>3</sub>** is true because we are told it is true. Thus, **P<sub>3</sub>** ≡ T by definition. But in the real world, (most of us) don't receive truths by divine revelation, we have to know things to infer things. Thus, while **P<sub>1</sub>** and **P<sub>2</sub>** might be obvious through perception, **P<sub>3</sub>** is not. To know if one is perceiving one's father, one must see him, and the mask prevents that. Thus, we have two additional propositions:

> **P<sub>4</sub>**: man = father
> **P'<sub>4</sub>**: man = ¬father

Unlike the first scenario, when we have three true propositions as givens (**P<sub>3</sub>** actually being given as **P<sub>4</sub>**), the second scenario we have two givens and have to infer **P'<sub>3</sub>** and are made conscious of the necessity of the inference.

Formally by thinking about the propostions as givens:

> **I<sub>1</sub>**: man<sub>f</sub> = father, masked(man<sub>m</sub>), man<sub>f</sub> = man<sub>m</sub> -> masked(man(father))
> **I<sub>2</sub>**: ∴ **P<sub>3</sub>**: K<sub>I</sub> "masked(father)"

that is opposed to thinking about the propositions as empirical facts:

> **I'<sub>1</sub>**: man<sub>f</sub> = father, masked(man<sub>m</sub>) -> ?masked(man(father))?
> **I'<sub>2</sub>**: ∴ **P<sub>3</sub>**: ¬K<sub>I</sub> "masked(father)"

So, it becomes clear that given the context of the judgment (three propositions that are given as true or three propositions which are true, but one which is NOT given), we arrive at the two contradictory conclusions at the same time. Since most of us do this quickly based on our intuition, it creates that icky, it-doesn't-seem logical feeling, and only through the process of sorting out the difference between reasoning with three true propositions, and two propsitions with one unknown truth value, do we understand the difference.

Comment: Thanks. I've also thought about it in the context of mathematics and computation. Can it be formalized in epistemic modal logic?

Comment: @J D any thoughts on my post-script?

Comment: @BenjaminGrange It can be formalized to give insight, but I'm not sure that requires or is permitted by epistemic modal logic given the lack of modality and necessity expressed in the propositions. I'll edit in my answer tomorrow morning.

Comment: I really appreciate it. I'll look through your answer in more detail as well. It's very good. :)

Comment: @BenjaminGrange I couldn't help myself. More interesting than debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I grappled with this question myself not too long ago and have come to conclude that in this particular puzzle there are two paths one can take to solve the problem:

1. **Clarifying the semantics of the premises** (This is by far the preferred method)

You provided the following premise -

> Premise 1: I don't know who the man wearing the mask is.

This premise can be interpreted in two ways; either as stating “the man behind the mask is a stranger to me (i.e. you don’t know him at all)” *or* “I am cannot ascertain the identity of the person behind the mask while the mask is on (i.e. the identity of the person is obscured from me).” It seems that in this context, the usage is clearly in line with the second interpretation; the issue is that of recognition and ascertaining identity, it’s that the identity of the individual behind the mask is obscured from you (due to the mask), not that you absolutely don’t know the person behind the mask (as in the first sense).

From there, it’s simply a matter of differentiating between your dad in different states. It’s quite plausible that you recognize your father when he’s not wearing a mask and you do not recognize him when he is.

Now if we rewrite the premise to reflect this, you get the following:

> Premise 1: I cannot ascertain the identity of the man wearing the mask while he’s wearing the mask.

> Premise 2: The man wearing the mask is my father.

> Premise 3: I know who my father is.

No absurdity is entailed from this. It’s not that you don’t know the individual behind the mask himself, but rather you cannot ascertain their identity. So, once again, let us substitute “know” with its appropriate sense in this context, though in both premises.

> Premise 1: I cannot ascertain the identity of the man wearing the mask while he’s wearing the mask.

> Premise 2: The man wearing the mask is my father.

> Premise 3: I can ascertain the identity of my father

Left in this form, once again a contradiction ensues (from 1 and 3) though this is easily ameliorated by restricting the scope of states your father must be in in order for you to be able to ascertain his identity. In this case, simply stating that you can do so when he is not in a mask suffices. Hence you get the following:

> Premise 1: I cannot ascertain the identity of the man wearing the mask while he’s wearing the mask.

> Premise 2: The man wearing the mask is my father.

> Premise 3: I can ascertain the identity of my father when he is not wearing a mask

2. **Examining the notion of identity used.**

The second method involves identity. As you said, the “is” here is taken as a “Liebnizian” identity operator, which means that the second premise is in effect stating that the man wearing the mask and your father share all intrinsic properties, though not necessarily all extrinsic properties (being known by you is an extrinsic property as it is not a property that inheres in an entity). In fact, such a property is also an *impure* property, which is explained as follows:

> A property is said to be impure if it is analysed in terms of a relation with some particular substance (e.g., being within a light year of the Sun). Otherwise it is pure (e.g., being within a light year of a star). Those two examples are both of extrinsic properties, but some intrinsic properties are impure, (e.g., being composed of the Earth and the Moon).

-*This is from an introductory entry on Leibniz’s law in the [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-indiscernible/)*

One or both such categories of properties are often excluded from the law, and a combination of both provides very strong grounds for excluding such a property from the scope of the identity operator. Therefore an absurd  conclusion doesn’t follow from the premise. To show this clearly, you end up with the following formulation:

> Premise 1: I don't know who the man wearing the mask is.

> Premise 2: The man wearing the mask and my father have all the same intrinsic (or pure) properties.

> Premise 3: I know who my father is.

Clearly an absurdity doesn’t follow here if being known by you is not an intrinsic or pure property, which it isn’t, hence the problem is avoided. Of course, if you use a stronger interpretation of the identity operator, then a contradiction follows from 1 and 3, in which case you would have to fall back on the semantic interpretation of the premises provided above.

That’s my two cents, please let me know if you have any questions or objections.

-Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is muddled thinking which simply confuses the objects of the word know. If you rephrase the description of the scenario as:

1. You know your father
2. You don't know wether it is your father wearing the mask

the supposed paradox disappears.